# Elegant way to strip() python

Tags: python, string, strip

I have to strip() my output of the DB with Python and it already works. But is there a more elegant way to do this?

Here is my code:

```
import MySQLdb
conn= MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","testPW","MixOMat")
c=conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT Zutat1 FROM Rezepte WHERE RezeptID=1")
z1=str(c.fetchall())
z1=z1.strip("(")
z1=z1.rstrip(")")
z1=z1.rstrip(",")
z1=z1.rstrip(")")
z1=z1.rstrip(",")
z1=z1.rstrip("L")
print(z1)
```

Comment: Would `rstrip("),L").lstrip("(")` work for you? What exactly does the string look like before you alter it, and what do you need it to look like afterwards?

Comment: show the initial `z1` value(before stripping)

Comment: As [the `str.strip` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) say, "The _chars_ argument is not a prefix or suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped"

Comment: This question lacks a proper example with the expected result after stripping.

Comment: Why on earth are you converting the result to a string? Just extract out the field or fields you want.

Comment: @Duncan That sounds sensible. I don't know `MySQLdb`, but I suspected this was an XY problem. Pity the OP couldn't show us some sample data...

Comment: So if I don't strip I get this Output: ((5L,),). But I need the 5 as a value to work with, later in the script.

Comment: `z1 = c.fetchone()[0]` will give you the 5.

Comment: Okay, I do it without the: [0] and it works. For what is this 0? @Duncan

Comment: The `[0]` is to take the first element from the tuple that is returned. But whatever works for you, just don't convert to a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, `.strip` parameter is the characters you want to remove, so you only need 2 calls

```
z1 = z1.strip('(').rstrip(')L')
```

Second, you're doing it wrong, the correct way to fetch your data should (I think) be:

```
c.execute("SELECT Zutat1 FROM Rezepte WHERE RezeptID=1")
(z1, ) = c.fetchone()
```

Note that I'm assuming you only have one row to retrieve

That will directly retrieve one integer instead of a string representation

Comment: Okay, thank you. That makes it a lot easier. Now I can work with the long value without stripping

Answer (score 1):

Just use a for loop

```
for e in ["(",")", ","...]:
    z1=z1.strip(e)
```

Functional aproach:

```
from functools import reduce

z1 = reduce(lambda x: z1.strip(x), ["(",")", ","...])
```

Or even just:

```
z1 = z1.strip("".join(["(",")", ","...]))
```

Comment: `"".join(["(",")", ","...])` Seriously? Why not just supply that arg as a literal? But anyway, this appears to be an XY problem, and the OP shouldn't be converting the object to a string & stripping it.

Comment: @PM2Ring, it doesnt really matter, but personally i like to separate to lists. anyway as you like.

Answer (score 0):

```
import MySQLdb
conn= MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","notna99","MixOMat")
c=conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT Zutat1 FROM Rezepte WHERE RezeptID=1")
z1=str(c.fetchall())
z1=z1.strip("(").rstrip(")").rstrip(",").rstrip(")").rstrip(",").rstrip("L")
print(z1)
```

This is the another way to do it or you can use slicing.